# How to score text tokens in a running total?

Tags: r, nlp, tidyverse

Given a table:

| text |
| --- |
| The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs |
| The cow jumped over the moon |

And a lookup table of tokens and values:

| keyword | value |
| --- | --- |
| jumped | 2 |
| over the | -1 |
| cow | 2 |

How do I construct a function in R that efficiently keeps a running score of the number of times a phrase appears?

The ideal outcome would be:

| text | score |
| --- | --- |
| The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs | 1 |
| The cow jumped over the moon | 3 |

Normally I'd use a for loop and iterate through the lookup table one row at a time, but I know there's probably a better way. I just don't know what it is. (bonus points for a tidyverse way of doing it!)

Thank you in advance for any links or guidance you can share to make this efficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to unnest_tokens, then do a join with the scoring table.